# How to set a color to different sub groups in barplot seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have a bar plot in which x-axis values ranges from 1 to 100.
I want to label each group of 50(1-50,51-100 and so on) with a specific color. Below is my current approach to label them but I don't know how to subgroup them-

```
ylabels = new_merged['time_A'].values.tolist()
xlabels = new_merged['Index'].to_list()
plt.figure(figsize=(100,50))
sns.barplot(xlabels, ylabels, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('Grader_A(Non-Medical)',fontsize=56)
plt.ylabel('Time taken per Image', fontsize=54)
plt.xlabel('Images', fontsize=54)
plt.savefig('Marco.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list for the color of each bar `['red', 'red', .... 'blue', 'blue'...]` where `'red'` is repeated 50 times, `'blue'` is repeated 50 times and so on..., then create a seaborn `color palette` from this list and pass this to the `sns.barplot` method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

## recreate some data
np.random.seed(42)
df_merged = pd.DataFrame({'time_A':np.random.normal(5.0, 1.0, 200)})

## this produces a palette that labels each group of 50 bars
palette = [color for color in ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple'] for _ in range(50)] 

plt.figure(figsize=(100,50))
sns.barplot(x=df_merged.time_A, y=df_merged.index, palette=sns.color_palette(palette))
plt.savefig('Marco.png')
```

[image]